# Delete rows that contains null value from dataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable that contains 7800 rows each row contains 3 column that may have Null values if the second column is null i am deleting the entire row the problem is that even when i am deleting the row the DataTable still contain the same amount of row number wish is 7800

the code :

```
 string query = "Select STORE_NAME, STORE_LATITUDE, STORE_LONGTITUDE "
  +" From stores inner join contact_information on stores.STORE_ID=contact_information.CONTACT_ID "
    +" where CONTACT_TYPE_ID=1 "
      +" AND CONTACT_COUNTRY_ID="+Country
         +" AND CONTACT_CASA_ID="+Casa
            +" AND CONTACT_TOWN_ID="+Town;
    DataTable dt = new SQLHelper(SQLHelper.ConnectionStrings.KernelConnectionString).getQueryResult(query);
    dt = removeNullColumnFromDataTable(dt);
```

the function :

```
    public static DataTable removeNullColumnFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
   {
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      {
       if (dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == null)
           dt.Rows[i].Delete();
      }
     return dt;
   }
```

Comment: `dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == "")` won't work.  "" is not the same as null.

Comment: i change it to null but it still the same

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public static void RemoveNullColumnFromDataTable(DataTable dt)
{
    for (int i = dt.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (dt.Rows[i][1] == DBNull.Value)
            dt.Rows[i].Delete();
    }
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Comment: it delete the row but the DataTable count still the same

Comment: I added `dt.AcceptChanges();` :)

Answer (score 1):

you can change first row to this (for sql server):

```
string query = "Select STORE_NAME, isnull(STORE_LATITUDE,'') as STORE_LATITUDE, STORE_LONGTITUDE "
```

and just check for empty string (if field type is char, varchar ... etc..)

```
dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == ""
```

or use isnull(STORE_LATITUDE,0) and check for zero dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == "0" if field type is numeric

Comment: the sql server change the null value to zero so i am kind of stuck with the same issue

Comment: dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() == ""

Comment: wait - what type of STORE_LATITUDE field ?

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DataRow> changedNotNull = (from r1 in changed
                                where r1.ItemArray[0] != DBNull.Value
                                select r1).ToList();
```

did the trick for me !